# FabricJS v. 2 beta – enable disable filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I am trying to apply and remove a filter to my active object. My code will apply the filter but will not remove it:

```
 $scope.contrastFilter = function () {
        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (!obj) return;

        if (obj.filters.Contrast) {
            obj.filters.Contrast = null;
        } else {
            obj.applyFilters([ new fabric.Image.filters.Contrast({ contrast: 15 })]);
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
   };
```

Comment: have you tried `stage.getActiveObject()` or `canvas.getActiveGroup()`?

Comment: I have tried it after your suggestion. In fact both will do nothing. canvas.getActiveObject() is applying the filter at least.

Comment: please add you canvas code

Comment: It is something like this – just can not recreate the functioning filter online: [ https://jsfiddle.net/sharksinn/pk1zz68s/7 ] – latest Chrome only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.contrastFilter = function() {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!obj) return;
    if (obj.filters[0]) {
        delete obj.filters[0];
    } else {
        obj.filters[0] = new fabric.Image.filters.Contrast({
            contrast: 15
        });
    }
    obj.applyFilters();
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

`obj.filters` is an array containing all filters, so while adding, push filter class to `obj.filters` and while removing , remove from that array.

Comment: This is sweet! Some questions on this: 1. Do I have to repeat this completly for all filters I would like to use? Or is there a way to define a filter array for contrast/blur/sepia/whatever in this function? 2. I duplicated this function for the blur filter. It is working for both filters, but I can assign only one filter to the object – applying a second one will delete the first one. 3. Is there a simple way to access the options (contrast or blur amount) from a slider etc. without having to write that for every filter separately?

Comment: I think I got at least one part ;-) (Qestion 1. and 2.) :  Using "obj.filters[0] / obj.filters[1] / obj.filters[2]" will do the job. Or is there an easier way to take it all in a single function? And Durga: THANKS! :-)

Comment: @SandorRozsa , you can check [there](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters) they are putting in specific index and then removing it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks – I know this demo. I just don't get it why all the timeStart and timeEnd stuff is there and what that is doing. To be honest, I prefere your solution. It is much more comprehensive fo a novice like me. I think you know my project – one of the goals of the project is to give also novice developers a chance to do some cool stuff with angular and fabric :-) But maybe you could enlight me regarding the time Star/End stuff ... ?

Comment: Guys the fabricjs demo code is not the pinnacle of engineering to look at. They are just to make the demo work. Please do not copy paste too much or you will have messy code at least. The timeEnd timeStart stuff is to measure how long took a filtering process, to report it in the interface as information.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to manage filtering on a fabric Image is:

Decide if a user can have multiple instance of a filter or not, and if it is always applied in the same order.

(contrast + saturation may differ from saturation + contrast)

Have a function to find the filter in the array of filters:

```
findFilterIndex(object, filterType) {
  var filterIndex = -1;
  var filter = object.filters.forEach(function(filter, index) { 
    if (filter.type === filterType) {
      filterIndex = index;
    }
  });
  return filterIndex;
}
```

And then as @Durga answered

```
$scope.contrastFilter = function() {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!obj) return;
    var index = findFilterIndex(obj, 'Contrast');

    if (index !== -1) {
        // fabric will keep it out from filtering
        obj.filters[index] = null;
    } else {
        obj.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Contrast({
            contrast: 15
        });
    }
    obj.applyFilters();
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

Take in consideration that creating a filter instance is cheap, but you do not have to create the new filter every time. you can still change the actual filter contrast value.

```
obj.filters[index].contrast = 15;
```

Comment: obj.filters[index] = null; //this line create error if same filter is apply and remove instead of this below line.
 used delete obj.filters[0];

Answer (score 0):

Enable and disable with same button here.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="f_polaroid">Polaroid </a>


$("#f_polaroid").on("click", function(event) {
    objetos = canvas4.getObjects('image');  

    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Polaroid();
    
    var index = findFilterIndex(objetos[0], 'Polaroid');
    if(index !== -1){
        delete objetos[0].filters[index] ;
    }else{
        objetos[0].filters.push(filter);
        //objetos[0].filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
    }
    //objetos[0].filters.push(filter);
    objetos[0].applyFilters();      
    canvas4.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function remove too, a filter from array filters.

```
fabric.util.removeFromArray(objetos[0].filters, 'Grayscale');
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="f_grayscale">Grayscale</a>

$("#f_grayscale").on("click", function(event) {
    objetos = canvas4.getObjects('image');  
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale(); 
    var index = findFilterIndex(objetos[0], 'Grayscale');
    if(index !== -1){
        delete objetos[0].filters[index] ;
    }else{
        objetos[0].filters.push(filter);
    }
    objetos[0].applyFilters();      
    canvas4.renderAll();
});
```